# Express - Error Handling Doesn't Work with Async Function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, error-handling, try-catch

So this is the POST request for /products, when a form is submitted, this function will be invoked.  I use a try-catch to catch the error if the form is submitted wrongly.

This is my Schema.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        enum: ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'dairy']
    }
});
```

The error is with the newProduct.save() line, so if I submit a form that goes against the Schema, like not having a name, I will get an error instead of getting redirected to the page.

```
app.post('/products', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
        newProduct.save();
        res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});
```

This is my error handler.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { status = 500, message = 'Something went wrong!' } = err;
    res.status(status).send(message);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `save` method is asynchronous and returns a promise. In your case, `newProduct.save()` returns a promise which is not being fulfilled and no error is actually thrown:

```
app.post('/products', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const newProduct = new Product(req.body);
        await newProduct.save();
        res.redirect(`/products/${newProduct._id}`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be validate `req.body` with a validator and save `newProduct` after it is validated. It'd be better to return the `newProduct` after it is saved rather than redirecting to certain endpoint.

If it is not validated you can throw your custom error.

I recommend using [JOI](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0) which is very easy to use.